# react native app instantly crashes when adding senderID to react-native-push-notification configure

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

react-native-push-notification works fine when calling `PushNotification.configure()` without `senderID`
however, when adding it, the app closes with no log.

platform: android (real device)

react-native-push-notification: ^3.0.2

react-native: 0.49.3

I tried `try catch` and tried sentry, both did not catch the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an incompatible version of play-services-gcm.

so I just changed `force=true` to `force=false` in `app/build.gradle`

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0') {
    force = false; <== Here
}
```